# Limit involving $(1+x)^x$ term

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I don't know how to solve the following limit without using series expansion.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+x)^x -1 -x^2}{x^3} $$

I have tried use L'Hopital's rule and finding bounds to use squeeze theorem but to no avail. Please give me hints on how to compute the limit, instead of posting full answers. Thanks in advance :)

---

Edit: I have just found an answer, though it is not elegant at all. It is done simply by applying L'Hopital's rule three times and there is not much to say about it. Still, other answers are welcome.

Comment: I didn't evaluate it by myself, but I guess you may try $(1+x)^x=e^{\ln (1+x)^x}$, and with the usage of theorem about limit of composition of continuous functions

Comment: @Eric but it one would still arrive at $\frac 00$ right?

Comment: well.. my way seems not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the limit with $x=1/p$, $p$ integer, $$\lim_{p\to\infty}p^3\left(\left(1+\frac1p\right)^{1/p}-1-\frac1{p^2}\right).$$

Multiplying/dividing by the conjugate multinomial we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p^3\left(1+\frac1p-\left(1+\frac1{p^2}\right)^p\right)
}
{\left(1+\frac1p\right)^{(p-1)/p}+\left(1+\frac1p\right)^{(p-2)/p}\left(1+\frac1{p^2}\right)+\cdots\left(1+\frac1{p^2}\right)^{(p-1)/p}}.$$

By the binomial theorem, the numerator is the finite sum

$$p^3\left(1+\frac1p-1-\frac p{p^2}-\frac{p(p-1)}{2p^4}-\frac{p(p-1)(p-2)}{3!p^6}-\cdots\frac1{p^{2p}}\right)\\
=-\frac{(p-1)}{2}-\frac{(p-1)(p-2)}{3!p^2}-\cdots\frac1{p^{2p-3}}$$ while the denominator has $p$ terms that are all between $1$ and $1+1/p$, hence is between $p$ and $p+1$.

In the limit, a single term remains, $$-\frac12.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

You can use the generalized binomial formula, which works for any exponent.

$$(1+x)^x\approx 1+x\cdot x+\frac{x(x-1)}2x^2+\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{3!}x^3+\cdots\binom xn{x^n}+\cdots$$

The coefficient of $x^3$ is $-\dfrac12$.

Comment: Only a *note*: The OP wants to have a solution without using series expansion. :-)

Comment: @user90369: mh, I was hoping that without referring to Taylor nobody would notice... :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Right right... but it can be recognized as Taylor from a mile away ;-)

Comment: @SkeletonBow: I have added a variant that only relies on the ordinary binomial theorem.

Comment: Ah yes, that's quite smart :)